# Attribute Error and excited with code=1 error in python in VS code

Tags: python

I am getting an AttributeError in Python when I try to extract sprites from an image using this code. The error message says

> ```
> type object 'spriteSheet' has no attribute 'spriteSheet'
> ```

How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```py
import pygame
from Test import spriteSheet

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 500
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Spritesheets')

sprite_sheet_image = pygame.image.load('doux.png').convert_alpha()
sprite_sheet = spriteSheet.spriteSheet((sprite_sheet_image))

BG = (50, 50, 50)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)


frame_0 = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 24, 24, 3, BLACK)
frame_1 = sprite_sheet.get_image(1, 24, 24, 3, BLACK)
frame_2 = sprite_sheet.get_image(2, 24, 24, 3, BLACK)
frame_3 = sprite_sheet.get_image(3, 24, 24, 3, BLACK)

run = True
while run:

    #update background
    screen.fill(BG)

    #show frame image
    screen.blit(frame_0, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(frame_1, (72, 0))
    screen.blit(frame_2, (150, 0))
    screen.blit(frame_3, (250, 0))

    #event handler
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Other file:

```py
import pygame

class spriteSheet():
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.sheet = image

    def get_image(self, frame, width, height, scale, colour):
        image = pygame.Surface((width, height)).convert_alpha()
        image.blit(self.sheet, (0, 0), ((frame * width), 0, width, height))
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (width * scale, height * scale))
        image.set_colorkey(colour)

        return image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a file called `Test` with a class `spriteSheet`. In your main file, you import `spriteSheet` with the line `from Test import spriteSheet` From here on, you now have a reference to the class `spriteSheet`. This means on line 13, you only need to write `sprite_sheet = spriteSheet(sprite_sheet_image)`.

Also, traditionally convention states that you should name your classes with upper camel case, so `SpriteSheet` in this case. Variables are then traditionally lower case. This makes it really easy to tell if you're working with an instance of a class or an instance of the class.

Comment: Minor correction: "you should name your classes with upper cases" I think you meant "camel case" or CapWords per [PEP8 naming conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names). `THISISUPPERCASE` while `ThisIsCamelCase`

Comment: Fair point, though technically camel case can be both `thisIsCamelCase` or `ThisIsCamelCase`. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: PEP8 refers to `ThisCaseConvention` as "CapWords" (https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names) - you sometimes see it called "Pascal case" too.